# jQuery UI Autocomplete showing two sources as soon as each is loaded

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

So I have a jQuery UI Autocomplete. What I am trying to do is make it show the combination of two results coming from a PHP file. The file can print either a normal PHP array (print_r) or a JSON string.

I have the Autocomplete working with one source, but the problem is my two sources are: first one super fast, the other takes time to come from database..

Anyway to make them appear separately, as soon as they load? I.e. when the first source finishes, it gets shown while the other one is loading from database.. and then once it is ready it is added to the end of the list already shown?

Thanks!

Comment: You can merge sources as you want after second source loaded, and than set merged source to jquery autocomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can overwrite 'search' method to show some kind of 'loading' gif while data is retrieving from database (using and Ajax call too could work)

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#method-option

EDIT: I don't know if this is going to work, but probably you will catch the global idea of what I want

```
var availableTags = [
   "ActionScript",
   "AppleScript",
   "Asp",
   "BASIC"
];
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
   source: availableTags
});

$.ajax({
   url: 'other_data.php'
   type: json,
   success: function(data){
      $('#tags').source = $('#tags').source.concat(data);
   }
});
```

Comment: Well, I already have this. It is just I want the user experience to be better, instead of waiting for the whole thing to load.

Comment: @johnshaddad I edited my own answer with other choice. I hope it helps you :)